# Spring : null pointer exception when calling service in controller

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I am using pure xml in spring configuration. I have `applicationContext.xml` and `servletContext.xml`. In applicationContext.xml, I created the dao and service bean while in servletContext.xml, I created controller bean that references the service bean in applicationContext. Then in controller class, I have this code to initialize the bean

```
private PersonService personService
public void setPersonService(PersonService personService){
 this.personService = personService;
}
```

When I call method in personService, Im getting a null pointer exception. I guess that the service bean is null. What am I doing wrong?

This is my beans xml
applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="personDao" class="com.training.hibernate.dao.impl.PersonDaoImpl">
      <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
      </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="personService" class="com.training.hibernate.services.impl.PersonServiceImpl">
      <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="personDao"/>
      </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

servletContext.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
   <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

   <bean class="com.training.hibernate.controller.PersonController">
      <property name="personService" ref="personService"/>
   </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
```

This is my controller

```
public class PersonController extends MultiActionController {

    private PersonService personService;

    public void setPersonService(PersonService PersonService){
        this.personService = personService;
    }

    public ModelAndView getAllPersons(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
        List<PersonDto> personDtos = personService.getAllPersons();
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
        model.addObject("persons",personDtos);
        model.addObject("roles",personService.getRoles());
        return model;
    }

    public ModelAndView add(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("person");
        return model;
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">
  <display-name>Spring Web Application</display-name>

  <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servletContext.xml</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: please post your bean xmls

Comment: If you haven't defined injection explicitly in xml file, you should put some injection annotation on your field. Like @Autowired private PersonService personService;

Comment: @bedrin he is not initiating the controller with component scanning, he is doing it as Bean.

Comment: Can you post controller Class and web.xml?

Comment: Are you not using @RequestMapping on Controller, to serve the request? Does this PersonController is a abstract class

Comment: Im not using @RequestMapping. I am using MultiactionController which my controller extends, and ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping bean to map the request. In my url bar, I type localhost:8080/person/getAllPersons.htm to access the getAllPersons method in the controller

Comment: I think you need to @Autowired PersonService in Controller

Comment: I have setter for personService so I think @Autowired is not needed

Comment: Yes, you have a setter but you also have to tell the Spring to use it. You can do that with @Autowired annotation, XML cofiguration file or JavaConfig class.